# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}x((1+1/x)^{1+1/x} - 1)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Having difficulty with solving this problem.
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\{x\left[\left(1 + {1 \over x}\right)^{1 + 1/x} - 1\right]\right\}
$$
I tried doing it with Bernoulli's inequality or something else, but I am lost.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please insert the question in the text of the question (not only in the title). Also, there must be some attempt to solve the exercise. Try to provide some context. Which is the source, which is the level, what have you tried?

Comment: I wanted to prove it's 1 with bernoulli's inequality and applying the squeeze theorem but I don't know what to write it's grater than and smaller than.

Comment: Do you have to use Bernoulli's inequality or will any method suffice?

Comment: any method works just fine, I wanted to try another method, that's why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substitution $y=1+\frac 1x$. Then $x=\frac 1{y-1}$. Let $f(y)$ be the function $f(y)=y^y=\exp(y\ln y)$. Then $f'(y)=\exp'(y\ln y)\cdot (y\ln y)'=y^y(\ln y+1)$. We get:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^{1+\frac 1x}-1\right)
=
\lim_{y\searrow 1}\frac1{y-1}\left(y^y-1\right)
=
\lim_{y\searrow 1}\frac{f(y)-f(1)}{y-1}
=
f'(1)
=
1\ .
$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac 1x}=e^{\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)}{x}}=e^{\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)}=1+\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$

and therefore

$$\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{1+\frac 1x}=\left(1+\frac1x\right)\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac 1x}=1+\frac1x+\frac1{x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$

and

$$x\left[\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{1+\frac 1x}-1\right]=1+\frac1x+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)\to 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\{x\left[\left(1 + {1 \over x}\right)^{1 + 1/x} - 1\right]\right\}$$
Substitute $z= 1+\dfrac 1x$:
$$L=\lim_{z \to 1}\left (\dfrac  {z^z-1}{z-1}\right)$$
Apply L'Hospital's rule:
$$L=\lim_{z \to 1}z^z(\ln z +1)$$
$$\implies L=1$$